# Apple WatchKit. How do you reopen the notificationView after pressing "dismiss" button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, watchkit, apple-watch

After you have run the "Notification" schema, and let's say u clicked on the "Dismiss" button,

[image]

how do you trigger an event that will make the view shown on the image above reappear?

Can it be done using local notifications? i am curious if there is a way to make this main view reappear. Even without using local notification if it comes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-run the Notification scheme. Local notifications are not supported in the simulator.